# Riemann Hurwitz vs Gauss Bonnet

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry

The Gauss-Bonnet theorem implies the Riemann Hurwitz theorem 
http://sma.epfl.ch/~troyanov/Papers/Prescribing.pdf
Prop 1 => Cor 2

In what sense is the Gauss- Bonnet theorem stronger?

Are these equivalent when deciding if a torus with prescribed conical singularities exists?

Comment: Gauss-Bonnet might imply Riemann-Hurwitz over $\mathbb{C}$, but Riemann-Hurwitz also holds over other fields.

Comment: Gauss-Bonnet theorem applies to surfaces with boundary and involves curvature (in fact, the boundary components need not be geodesic). By contrast, Riemann-Hurwitz theorem is topological in nature.

Comment: I'm trying to decided if a torus with prescribed conical singularities exists.  Does Gauss Bonnet give extra information in this setting?  Say I want to tile a torus with squares with four meeting at each vertex and two along each edge.  Except I want to put in two special vertices: one where three squares meet and one where 5 squares meet.  By Riemann-Hurwitz this exists (although I can't draw it).  Does Gauss Bonnet give additional obstructions?

Comment: You should state your question on "torus with conical singularities" more precisely. What is your assumption about the metric away from conical singularities? If it is flat (or has negative curvature), no other restrictions except Gauss Bonnet is necessary. Otherwise, there may be  complicated restrictions.

Comment: The metric away from the conical singularities is flat.  So in this case, Gauss Bonnet does not give more information than Riemann Hurwitz?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed the Gauss-Bonnet condition is the only obstruction to building a flat metric with conical singularities on a compact surface. As mentioned by Eremenko the same result also holds with (prescribed) negative curvature (say constant -1) but the story is more complex for positive curvature. There is a vast literature on the subject starting with the paper you cited.
For the flat case a short proof is in my paper
[http://sma.epfl.ch/~troyanov/Papers/Enseign.Math_1986.pdf](http://sma.epfl.ch/%7Etroyanov/Papers/Enseign.Math_1986.pdf)